# Two-Tier ML Model to Predict Data Relevance

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, references

I'm dealing with a video classification ML problem where there are ~10k total scenes, each labeled with a category I need to predict. The problem is that each scene consists of ~100 separate videos (taken at different times from different angles), and only ~10% of the videos from any given scene actually contain relevant information for classification. A model should be able to analyze any given relevant video and correctly classify the scene that it came from, but an irrelevant video would be effectively useless. The relevant videos aren't labeled, so I effectively need two different models: model "A" should classify videos as relevant or irrelevant, and model "B" should classify relevant videos into various categories.

The straightforward approach would be for me to manually generate enough relevancy labels to train A and then train B on whatever is identified as relevant. However, this would require a lot of tedious manual labeling and may obscure unexpected relevancy in some videos. I'm curious whether anyone has tried a more data-driven iterative approach, something like the following:

1. Pick a random subset of videos and train B to predict a category label. After a bit of training, record which videos B gets correct or incorrect.
2. Train A to predict which videos B would get correct or incorrect
3. Pick a new random subset of videos that A thinks will be classified correctly, then return to step 1 and repeat until both models converge

The hope is that since B can only get consistently correct answers on relevant videos, A will learn to predict relevancy and B will learn how to classify those relevant videos. Has anyone seen this type of approach tried before? Is there an example published anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This question is interesting, but I dispute its premise. If you will have videos to classify that contain little information related to the classification, I would want to keep track of how I do on those so I know to expect low accuracy on ambiguous videos and can fold that into my model evaluation. It’s not ideal to make poor predictions, but it’s worse to make poor predictions when you think you’re making good ones!

Comment: Thanks Dave, I realized that I didn't state my problem clearly enough (it's been edited now above). What I'm really after is "scene" classification, and I want to narrow down the data within each scene to the parts that contain relevant information.